# Tag reputation from edits

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, badges

I have noticed that when I edit a post with a tag, say C#, sometimes it shows under my reputation a plus two value with the message:

> "Reputation gained on this tag since your last visit to the reputation
>   tab."

Does this reputation count toward the tag badges or is that reputation gained only for asking and answering questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tag badges only count the number of upvotes you have received for non-wiki answers to questions with that tag. As the description of the bronze tag badge says:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Reputation gained for editing posts with the tag, or for asking questions with the tag, does not count.

And as a general reminder, it counts the answer score, not the reputation score (e.g. 10 upvotes is 100 reputation, but only 10 points toward your total score for a given badge).